# C programming, doing multiple calculations in one function

Tags: c

Is it possible to create a function and do multiple calculations in that function, then create another function to print out the results of the calculations... I know a function can only return one value.

Comment: `struct`s are your friend.

Comment: As "one return value" it can be a bag of values.

Comment: You can set multiple values by passing pointer arguments to be set by the function. Or you can define a `struct` which contains all the results, and return that as the function value.

Comment: You want to check one of these paper-thingies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to return multiple values.  One way is to "package" them as a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  int x;
  float y;
} Result;

Result add2( int x1, int x2, float y1, float y2)
{
  Result r;
  r.x = x1 + x2;
  r.y = y1 + y2;
  return r;
}
```

Another way to do it is to use parameters as your outputs:

```
void add2( int x1, int x2, float y1, float y2, int* x, float* y)
{
  *x = x1 + x2;
  *y = y1 + y2;
}
```

You could also do combinations of these.

Comment: You need a `typedef` in order to use `Result` without the `struct`  keyword.

Comment: That's a good example, but when all the fields in the `struct` are of the same type, you could achieve the same by using an array. A better example (more general one) is if they were of different types.

Comment: @SHG: Just because you *can* achieve the same result with an array, doesn't mean it's preferable to. A two-dimensional coordinate value, for example, would be better represented as a `struct` than as a two-element array. And obviously you can't return an array from a function, so if you wanted to do this, you'd still need to wrap it in a `struct`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Right. I didn't say it's preferable, just that you can. And if you show an example for a concept, make it general. Obviously one of the advantages of a struct would be to be able to return different types, so it's better to be demonstrated as well.

Answer (score 3):

One return value is for wimps! Simply define the function as

```
struct retval { int i; double d; size_t z; } func(void);
```

(replacing the contents of the struct and the parameters as applicable).

Be careful when doing this, though. In spite of what I said up top, in general there is no need for multiple returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a struct with all the things ​​you are interested in, alloc it on heap, edit it inside a function, return the same struct that you have edited and at the end free the memory.
Alternatively, you can also pass the pointer and at the end free the memory.

Example:

```
typedef struct date_test {
int year;
int month;
int day;
} Date;
```

With this you create a structure that will contain 3 int values: year, month and day.

Alloc it on heap and check for errors:

```
Date *test = malloc(sizeof(Date));
if (test == NULL) {
    perror("Malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Edit it inside a function and return the struct, example:

```
Date* test_f(Date* test)
{
    test->year = 2017;
    test->month = 05;
    test->day = 29;
    return test;
}
```

Then free the allocated memory:

```
free(test);
```

Comment: You don't need to `return test;` in this case.